# Placeholder for option in a Select

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

So I'm having ​​a huge difficulty adding a placeholder under my option. If anyone could help and tell me how to have a placeholder that is just the typical " pick a language " or a dynamic one I would really appreciate it.

```
<label for="language">Language</label>

<select class="browser-default" ng-model="profession.language.id">
 <option placeholder="profession_language.name" ng-repeat="profession_language in languages" class="validate" value="{{profession_language.id}}">{{profession_language.name}}</option
</select>
```

Comment: Don't link to a screenshot of your code. Paste it directly as code-formatted text in your question so it's easier for others to read and search. Also, post what issues is this code causing and why is it not working like you want. That should make it easier for others to help you out.

Answer (score 2):

Add a option tag like this one.

```
<option value="" disabled selected>Placeholder</option>
```

Comment: That was my first go 2 but it ends like this 
http://imgur.com/a/BapNe

Answer (score 1):

```
<option value="" disabled selected data-ng-hide="profession.language_id">Some Value</option>
```

Nghide will remove the placeholder when a value is selected from the dropdown